# Bash Script to encrypt file taken in as parameter from user

Tags: bash, openssl, aes, ubuntu-16.04, quoting

I have the following issue. I have a bash script that when executed asks the user what file they wish to encrypt. The script works fine, the issue is when there is spaces in the file name. I have tried the following

```
read -p "Enter file name ..." test;
openssl enc -e -aes256 -in "'$test'" -out $test.enc -k -pass:$PASS
```

I get the following error msg

> enc: Cannot open input file 'd d', No such file or directory

This line works in the bash script and if run in terminal

```
openssl enc -e -aes256 -in 'd d' -out enc.enc -k -pass:$PASS
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Remove both `'`.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Use test variable in double quote - "$test"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have tried without the single quote, i.e using "$test". The issue then is that the user us asked to enter the password manually and not the password saved in $PASS, see below
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OpenSSL 1.1.0f you should use -passin:

```
read -p "Enter file name ..." test;
openssl aes-256-cbc -in "$test" -out "$test".enc -k -passin pass:"$PASS"
```